# Displaying a local time in Haskell

Tags: haskell, timezone

My state object is storing dates as `UTCTime`. But I need to show them to the user as the appropriate local time.

I've tried using `getCurrentTimeZone` and then `utcToLocalTime`, but it doesn't work for dates in summer-time. The problem seems to be that `getCurrentTimeZone` returns my timezone *now*, not for the appropriate date.

```hs
let time = UTCTime (fromGregorian 2018 08 08) 0
tz <- getCurrentTimeZone -- GMT - my time zone now
utcToLocalTime tz time
-- 2018-08-08 00:00:00 - wrong
```

I can get it to work if I pass the date into `getTimeZone`:

```hs
let time = UTCTime (fromGregorian 2018 08 08) 0
tz <- getTimeZone time -- BST - the timezone for the date
utcToLocalTime tz time
-- 2018-08-08 01:00:00 - right
```

The problem is, the code to set/display the time is deep into no-`IO` land (as it should be), so I can't run this code when I want to display the times.

I've had a look at the [Olsen package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/timezone-olson-0.1.9/docs/Data-Time-LocalTime-TimeZone-Olson.html), but when I passed it `GMT` (using `timeZoneName`) it did the same as the first example above - couldn't work out how else to tell it to get the data.

Comment: Looks like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tz-0.1.2.1/docs/Data-Time-Zones.html might work

Answer (score 2):

The intended way of doing this with the `timezone-olson` package is to use a `TimeZoneSeries` which is the full series of time zone transitions over time, rather than merely a `TimeZone`, which reflects the time zone at a point in time.

You will generally need to load the appropriate series from a file in `IO`.  You can load the default local time zone series from the standard `/etc/localtime` location, or you can load a specific series from, for example, `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago` or whatever.  Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a robust, platform-independent way to specify and load time zone files.

Once the `TimeZoneSeries` is read, it needs to be passed down to your pure computations, where you can use `utcToLocalTime'` to get a correct local time using the time zone for that time point.  Hopefully you already have a `Reader` handy:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.Time (UTCTime(..), fromGregorian, LocalTime)
import Data.Time.LocalTime.TimeZone.Olson (getTimeZoneSeriesFromOlsonFile)
import Data.Time.LocalTime.TimeZone.Series (TimeZoneSeries, utcToLocalTime')

data R = R { tzs :: TimeZoneSeries }

main :: IO ()
main = do
  mytzs <- getTimeZoneSeriesFromOlsonFile "/etc/localtime"
  print $ runReader getTimes R { tzs = mytzs }

getTimes :: Reader R LocalTime
getTimes = flip utcToLocalTime' (UTCTime (fromGregorian 2018 08 08) 0) <$> asks tzs
```

It looks like the `tz` package is the same, though it uses type `TZ` in place of `TimeZoneSeries`.  You still need to `loadTZFromFile` in `IO` and pass it down to a `utcToLocalTimeTZ` call located in your pure code.  There is a convenience function `loadLocalTZ` that reads from `/etc/localtime` (or an alternate location specified by the `TZ` environment variable); it *looks* platform-independent, but the `/etc/localtime` and `/usr/share/zoneinfo` paths are hard-coded in the source (except it uses the environment variable `TZDIR` in place of `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, if that's set).

Anyway, the code would look like:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.Time (UTCTime(..), fromGregorian, LocalTime)

import Data.Time.Zones (utcToLocalTimeTZ, loadLocalTZ, TZ)

data R = R { tz :: TZ }

main :: IO ()
main = do
  mytz <- loadLocalTZ
  print $ runReader getTimes R { tz = mytz }

getTimes :: Reader R LocalTime
getTimes = flip utcToLocalTimeTZ (UTCTime (fromGregorian 2018 08 08) 0) <$> asks tz
```

Comment: I got it working with a `TimeZoneSeries`, it just wouldn't give me the right time. Maybe I needed to use `/etc/localtime` - hadn't found that.